# What are the skepticism ideas Nagel refers to in "The Absurd"?

Tags: reference-request, skepticism

In Thomas Nagel's article "[The Absurd](http://www.pitt.edu/~kis23/ABSURD.pdf)", there's this note:

> I am aware that skepticism about the external world is widely thought to
>   have been refuted, but I have remained convinced of its irrefutability since being exposed at Berkeley to Thompson Clarke's largely unpublished ideas on 
>   subject. (p. 723)

I have two questions:

1. Whose - or what - idea is Nagel referring to when he says that skepticism about the external world is thought to have been refuted?
2. Were those Thompson Clarke's ideas published later? Where can I read about them? I have "The Legacy of Skepticism" on queue to read, but I'll appreciate if someone gives me more specific recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

I picked these pearls of texts [Clark](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://cas.uchicago.edu/workshops/germanphilosophy/files/2011/05/clarke-The-Legacy-of-Skepticism.pdf&ei=NrR_UZfTE8nL0AHCmYHIDA&usg=AFQjCNG9B8BorW-j7Mw96Fpf9X0ALUvIMw&sig2=FhCCuusL7wR-2mjd_Sp_jA&bvm=bv.45645796,d.eWU) and [Nagel](http://www.pitt.edu/~kis23/ABSURD.pdf):

> Clark 
> We are forced wine tasters of the conceivable. Acknowledging
>   this, I feel condent, nevertheless, that it is inconceivable that I
>   could now be asleep, dreaming, if no outsider could know my real
>   environs because in the same boat, for the same reason, because he,
>   too, could not know he was not asleep, dreaming. Does Descartess
>   possibility even seem to make sense, if we ask ourselves how the Evil
>   Demon, or God, could know that he, too, wasn't  dreaming and allow
>   that neither could?
>
> […] Skepticism frees us from antiquated problems, including itself,
>   offering us a new, challenging problem.[...] Skepticism leaves us the
>   problem of the plain, of its structure, the character and source of
>   its relative “non-objectivity,” and one major tool for unlocking its
>   secrets, the plain skeptical possibilities. How radically that
>   structure must differ from the standard type, if capable of permitting
>   concepts with the characteristics of Dream to be concepts, and the
>   plain skeptical possibilities to be possibilities, is evident
>   enough.[...]
>
> Nagel
>   [...]The certainty that we are not dreaming cannot be justified except
>   circularly, in terms of those very appearances which are being put in
>   doubt. It is somewhat far-fetched to suggest I may be dreaming; but
>   the possibility is only illustrative. It reveals that our claims to
>   knowledge depend on our not feeling it necessary to exclude certain
>   incompatible alternatives, and the dreaming possibility or the
>   total-hallucination possibility are just representatives for limitless
>   possibilities most of which we cannot even conceive.
>
> I am aware that skepticism about the external world is widely thought
>   to have been refuted, but 1 have remained convinced of its
>   irrefutability since being exposed at Berkeley to Thompson Clarke's
>   largely unpublished ideas on the subject.

In 1971 Nagel is probably referring to the supposed refutation of skepticism by [Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_is_one_hand). What Nagel and Clarke are saying is that Moore's arguments only prove that common sense is a possible way of describing the world, and they say that other forms are possible and incompatible. Hence the skeptic instead of asking how I justify that common sense is correct, he ask now how to know which among the possible ways of describing the world is the correct one.
I personally don't like the skeptic's refutation of Moore, but the refutation via [semantic externalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_externalism).
I don't know Thompson Clarke's references.